# проверка существоваание базы данных SQLite

Tags: android, c#, xamarin

У меня два Activity! В первом я создаю БД

```
 db = new DataBase();

 db.CreateDataBase();
```

Метод CreateDataBase выглядит так

```
public bool CreateDataBase()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(System.IO.Path.Combine(folder, "Items.db")))
            {
                connection.CreateTable<Item>();
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch(SQLiteException ex)
        {
            Log.Info("SQLiteEx", ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Мне нужно во втором Activity обратиться к уже существующей БД, а подходящего метода я найти не могу.
Как спасти ситуацию?

Answer (score 0):

Создайте отдельный класс (MyApp) в котором у вас будут все операции с базой. 
Затем в activity в котором вам нужно обращаться к базе, используйте getApplication();

```
SQLiteDatabase myDB;
  @Override protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    myDB = ((MyApp)getApplication()).myDB;
  }
```

Comment: я пишу на xamarine. Здесь так не прокатывает. Нужен другой подход.

Comment: Вы собираетесь получать какое то значение из базы во втором активити или оперировать с базой?